# fadeToggle() not functioning

Tags: coffeescript, ruby-on-rails-5

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
 <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
   <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/r29/html5.min.js">
   </script>
 <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>

  <section class="dropdown-text">
    <p><%= link_to "My text", "#", id: "text-link" %></p>
    <div id="my-text">
       my text
    </div>
  </section>


</body>
</html>
```

.coffee:

```
$(document).on "ready page:load", ->
  $("section.dropdown-text").on "click", "#text-link",  ->
    $("#my-text").fadeToggle()
    e.preventDefault()
```

If I click on the link nothing happens. I assume the mistake is silly but I just can't find it. Also happy to provide more details if necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code:

<**/**section class="dropdown-text">

<%= link_to "My text", "#", id: "text-link" %>

my text

The "section" element is not enclosed correctly.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that but that was just a mistake while copying the code.